# OnCollisionEnter2D для наследника

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть абстрактный класс:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public abstract class Tank : MonoBehaviour
{
   public float HP;    // здоровье
   public float moveSpeed; // скорость движения
   public float rotateSpeed;   // скорость поворота

   public void MoveForward(float weakness)
   {
       transform.position += transform.up * moveSpeed * weakness;
   }

   public void MoveBack()
   {
       transform.position -= transform.up * moveSpeed;
   }

   public void MoveRight()
   {
    float angle = transform.rotation.z;
    transform.Rotate(0f, 0f, -rotateSpeed, Space.World);
   }

   public void MoveLeft()  
   {
       float angle = transform.rotation.z;
       transform.Rotate(0f, 0f, rotateSpeed, Space.World);
   }

   public void TakingDamage(float damage)
   {
       HP -= damage;
   }
```

}

И класс мины:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Bomb : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float damage;

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        Tank tank = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Tank>();
        tank.TakingDamage(damage);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Если я правильно понял - бомба взрывается только при столкновении с членом класса Tank, однако этого не происходит при столкновении с наследником данного класса. Как же заставить бомбу взрываться при столкновении с игроком? Возможно, использовать теги?

Comment: может из за private?

Comment: Нет, private здесь не при чем. Только то пробовал, но наследник будто не видит бомбу.

Comment: коллайдеры на месте?

Comment: Нужно настроить коллайдер для всех объектов? Не знал.

Comment: именно он используется для проверки коллизий

Comment: как вариант, да, через теги, только используйте `CompireTag()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ты получаешь компонент типа Tank
Если столкновение мины произошло с каким-то другим объектом у тебя переменная tank равна null.
Тебе как минимум нужно делать проверку на это.

И при этом, если у класса Tank есть наследники, то эти классы всё равно отличаются и не есть класс Tank.

Так что тебе придётся получать компонент столкновения для каждого объекта с которым мина может столкнуться, и не важно наследуются их классы каким-либо образом или нет.

Почему? потому что при столкновении, скажем класса Player который к примеру наследует класс Tank. Столкновение всё равно происходит от имени класса Player.

И код должен будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    Tank tank = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Tank>();
    Player player  = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Player>();
    if(tank != null) {
        tank.TakingDamage(damage);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
    if(player != null) {
        //TODO: player's behaviour
    }
}
```

Comment: P.S. ещё ты можешь использовать преобразования LINQ что бы брать один объект и смотреть подходит ли его тип, а-ля `object is Tank`

Comment: вряд ли, тогда бы упал наллпоинтер

Comment: @StrangerintheQ тоже верно, но логов из консоли я не видел, так что и на этот счёт тоже ничего сказать не получится, ведь юнити из-за такого не вылетает а просто пишет лог

Comment: В таком случае нет смысла прописывать скрипт для столкновения с классом, у которого даже объекты создать нельзя, а просто создать класс игрока и присвоить ему значение нужного игроку наследника.